# Unidirectional @OneToOne relationship with different Entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, orm

I have a `User` class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

that models an user account that could be for a `Student` or a `Teacher`. They can own only one account so to specify this relationship I thought to model it by a @OneToOne relationship but I'm having trouble understanding if it would be a good idea to make that unidirectional.

Also, the `User` class could refer both to a `Student` and a `Teacher` by logic, what if I need to retrieve the details of the user starting from its `User` account? From my understanding, I should create a bi-directional relationship, but, which entity do I need to put inside the `User` class?

Answer (score -1):

You can use an enumeration:

```
public enum UserType {
    STUDENT("Student"),
    TEACHER("Teacher");


    private final String displayValue;

    UserType(String displayValue) {
        this.displayValue = displayValue;
    }
    public String getDisplayValue() {
        return displayValue;
    }
}
```

And in your user entity:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserType userType;


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no bi-directional relationship

Comment: Yes but why do you need a bidirectional relationship ? In this configuration a user can be a student or a teacher.

Comment: to retrieve the person details starting from ``User``

Comment: What can't you retrieve in the configuration I'm proposing?